# Remove Spacing between two custom cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView on mainStoryboard with two custom cells. I would like to reduce the spacing between two cells. 
I was trying to find the answer but could not find any. I have image and code added below.

[image]

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tblStoryList: UITableView!

    var array = PLIST.shared.mainArray



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    //spacing between header and cell
        self.tblStoryList.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, 0, 0)

      //delete separator of UITableView
    tblStoryList.separatorStyle = .none

    }
   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.array.count + 1
    }



     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
            cell.headerTitle.text = "First Stage"
            return cell
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoryTableviewCell", for: indexPath) as! StoryTableviewCell


        //making plist file
        let dict = self.array[indexPath.row - 1]
        let title = dict["title"] as! String
        let imageName = dict["image"] as! String
        let temp = dict["phrases"] as! [String:Any]
        let arr = temp["array"] as! [[String:Any]]
        let detail = "progress \(arr.count)/\(arr.count)"

        //property to plist file
        cell.imgIcon.image = UIImage.init(named: imageName)
        cell.lblTitle.text = title
        cell.lblSubtitle.text = detail

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none


        return cell
    }
```

header cell

```
 import UIKit

class HeaderCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var headerTitle: UILabel!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        headerTitle.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        headerTitle.layer.masksToBounds = true


    }



}
```

Comment: it seems you are setting same height for both types. Set height differently for both cell

Comment: share code for cell generation

Comment: Its look like you are using 2 different kind of cells for you that you need to return different heights based on each cell. Right now you are returning standard height for each cell

Comment: it might possible that you have set wrong constraints ! or you are returning same height for both cells from heightForRow delegate! Show your heightForRow or estimatedHeightForRow method whatever you have implemented!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have set some static height to the cells in `heightForRowAt indexPath` method, set it to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. and `estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath` set it to static value for better performance.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40 //expected minimum height of the cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

And not to forget that you need to set "correct constraints" to get the desired result by this method. Constraints are required to let know the table cell about its height.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I edited my answer with code, I dont set "heightForRowAt indexPath method", and there is no error with constraints.

Comment: No you have to attach top and bottom of cell to the UI Elements, and each element should be connected to each other (top, bottom). For example, remove the centre vertical constraint of the first cell button and add top and bottom constraint to it. The first cell will look fine!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return height for each cell accordingly . for example

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
          // return height for first row, i.e
          return 40
        }
        // return height for other cells. i.e
        return 90

    }
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. I wrote your code but it only change each height of the cell. Not space between two custom cells....

Comment: want to do small teamviewer session?

Comment: Ok but its not video chat

Comment: Thanks I just added the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144334/discussion-between-shabir-jan-and-risa8).

Answer (score 0):

You can set table each and every cell height dynamic with Autolayout table view will take cell hight from Autolayout 
for that you dont need write this 2 method

Remove this method

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
CGFloat 
{
}
```

Write this 2 line in ViewDidload method

```
 self.tblView?.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 self.tblView?.estimatedRowHeight = 60
```

And set your imageview bottom space with Autolayout that you want to keep for example 10 and set relation of bottom layout is greater then or equal and set priority is 252 instead of 1000

You will get clear idea about this in my screen shot check that as well how to do this Do this in all custom cell this way you can set height dynamic no need to calculate height of each and every cell and not need to return

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 0; // in viewdidload
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone]; // in viewdidload

 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 0.01f;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return <your header height>;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return <your header view>;
}
```

Also have table seprator as none.

Comment: Question is tagged with swift, so you should write answer in swift!

Comment: Sorry, new to stackoverflow. Sorry for the mistake.