# UIView Size in Custom UITableViewcell after AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

There is a view1(UIView) in Custom UITableViewCell in I need new size of view1(UIView) after AutoLayout

UITableViewCell content is dynamic, hence I used UITableViewAutomaticDimension for self resizing

I also use below methods but I get Original Size. I can not get new size of view1(UIView) after expanding

```
[self.tblView1 setNeedsLayout];
[self.tblView1 layoutIfNeeded];
[cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
[cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];   
[cell.view1 setNeedsLayout];
[cell.view1 layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: UITableViewAutomaticDimension gives dynamic cell size not dynamic view size.

Comment: Follow this answer this will help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43999765/1679754

Comment: @TusharSharma JigneshMayani

Yes UITableViewAutomaticDimension gives dynamic cell size.

But how I get new size of UIView.
My cell successfully expand and decrease according to content.
Actually I want to draw Left Right Lower Border for UIView.
but border draw according to its original size not according to New size of UIView

Comment: CALayer *leftBorder = [CALayer layer];

            leftBorder.backgroundColor = [[HexToRGBColor colorFromHexString:[dictTblData objectForKey:@"cd_color"] alpha:1] CGColor];
            leftBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 3, cell.viewContent.frame.size.height);
            [cell.viewContent.layer addSublayer:leftBorder];

Comment: Where did you added this code? add above code in layoutSubview()

Comment: @karthikeyan
How I add this code in layoutSubview()? because this is code of Custom UITableViewCell

Comment: Override layoutSubview it in your custom cell file

Comment: @karthikeyan I added layoutSubview() this method to CustomCell File but there is no effect and control also do not reach to layoutSubview() method

Comment: @karthikeyan 
My cell successfully expand and decrease according to content. Actually I want to draw Left Right Lower Border for UIView. but border draw according to its original size not according to New size of UIView
I added layoutSubview() in CustomCell.m but there is no effect

Comment: What are your constraints?

Comment: @Koen 
constraints related superview top,left,right 10Px margin Bottom side 0 margin all 4 constraints related to SuperView in UITableViewcell

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/